# Pinned example in document topic is overlapping with text

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-topics

Seems like a small bug with pin alignment on topic examples in our new documentation section. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rubygems/drafts/19345) to the relevant document.

[image: Pin example style issue]

Just thought about giving the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing a fix for this in the next production build. Should be live soon. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Nice to hear that. Really loving this documentation addition +1 :)